# Create video from image (fit but not stretch)

Tags: image, ffmpeg, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to create video from image but it's fit to video size (hd). How to keep aspect ratio of my image BUT get 1280 x 720 video?

Here is current result (image is 3264 x 2448 px, video 1280 x 720 px):

[image]

Here is my current command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i IMAGE_PATH -t 3 -s hd720 -c:v mpeg4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast RESULT_PATH
```

Should I divide my task to two operations (generate image with black stripes then generate video)? Could you help to modify command to get desired result?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use [`aspect`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) though you specify the `s` in the command.

```
-aspect 3264/2448
```

And also try [`pad`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) to get the black bars around the output video without stretching the video to fit the screen size. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/690021/video-padding-using-ffmpeg) question is about that.

Hope this will help you!